# Manual calculation of McKelvey & Zavoina Pseudo $R^2.$

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

I would like to calculate McKelvey & Zavoina pseudo $R^2$ manually for poisson regression. I based my calculations on the formula found [here](https://datascience.oneoffcoder.com/psuedo-r-squared-logistic-regression.html) i.e.

$$ R^2 =\frac{\sigma^2(\hat y) }{\sigma^2(\hat y)+ \frac{\pi^2}3}$$

Let's consider the following model:

```
set.seed(42)
y <- c(1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3)
x <- rnorm(length(y))
z <- runif(length(y))

mod <- glm(y ~ x + z, family = poisson)
```

And my calculation of pseudo $R^2$ is then:

```
var(predict(mod)) / (var(predict(mod)) + pi^2 / 3)
0.02075299
```

However, if we calculate this $R^2$ using `performance` library, we obtain:

```
performance::r2_mckelvey(mod)
0.1853505
```

Do you know, what the source of this discrepancy is?

Answer (score 1):

To see the code behind a function, you can type the function name without `()` at the end. Sometimes the top level functions only do methods dispatch so you have to find out which function is called by the top-level function. But in the end, these are the relevant functions in your case:

```
performance:::.r2_mckelvey <- function (model) {
    faminfo <- insight::model_info(model)
    n <- insight::n_obs(model, disaggregate = TRUE)
    if (faminfo$is_binomial || faminfo$is_ordinal || faminfo$is_multinomial) {
    dist.variance <- switch(faminfo$link_function, probit = 1, 
        logit = pi^2/3, clogloglink = pi^2/6, NA)
    } else if (faminfo$is_count) {
        # this line is where the residual variance is calculated,
        # in your case `.get_poisson_variance` is called (see below)
        dist.variance <- switch(faminfo$link_function, log = .get_poisson_variance(model), 
            sqrt = 0.25, 0)
    }
    y.hat <- stats::predict(model, type = "link")
    yhat_columns <- ncol(y.hat)
    if (!is.null(yhat_columns) && yhat_columns > 1) 
        y.hat <- as.vector(y.hat[, 1])
    # the two following lines are where the main calculations happen
    # (compare this to your code)
    dist.residual <- sum((y.hat - mean(y.hat))^2)
    mckelvey <- dist.residual/(n * dist.variance + dist.residual)
    names(mckelvey) <- "McKelvey's R2"
    mckelvey
}

performance:::.get_poisson_variance <- function (model) {
    mu <- exp(stats::coef(.null_model(model)))
    if (is.na(mu)) {
        return(0)
    }
    cvsquared <- stats::family(model)$variance(mu)/mu^2
    log1p(cvsquared)
}
```

As you can see, the source of the discrepancy is that this formula uses the residual sum of squares and computes the variance in a different way (log-normal approximation; second function).

**Edit 08-08-2023: statistical reasoning**

Following [McKelvey and Zavoina (1975)](https://doi.org/10.1080/0022250X.1975.9989847):
$$R² = \frac{S_E^2}{\hat{S_T^2}}\tag{eq. 3.21}$$
$S_E^2$ being the residual sum of squares and $\hat{S_T^2}$ the total sum of squares defined as
$$\hat{S_T^2} = S_E^2 + \hat{S_R^2} = S_E^2 + n \sigma^2 \tag{eq. 3.20 and 3.18}$$
(not assuming unit variance), which is exactly in line with the above code (`mckelvey <- dist.residual/(n * dist.variance + dist.residual)`). Then, as explained in [Nagakawa et al. (2017)](https://doi.org/10.1098/rsif.2017.0213#d1e1667), for Poisson with log-link $\sigma^2$ can be estimated by the lognormal approximation, as:
$$\sigma^2 = ln(1 + \frac{1}{\lambda}) \tag{tbl. 1 and §5}$$
with $\lambda$ approximated from $exp(β0)$ from the intercept-only model, which translates to `exp(stats::coef(.null_model(model)))` (note that `mu` in the code is $\lambda$ in Nagakawa's equation). Since with the Poisson model family `stats::family(model)$variance(mu)` is equal to `mu`, `log1p(stats::family(model)$variance(mu)/mu^2)` is equivalent to `log(1 + 1/mu)`.

Comment: It’s good advice to look at the code itself to see what calculations are being performed, but I have to wonder about the statistical reasoning behind doing these calculations.

Comment: @Dave, I have edited the answer to show where the code comes from

Answer (score 0):

At least according to the documentation for the R package *performance*, that formula for McKelvey and Zavoina pseudo *r*-squared is only for binomial logistic regression with the logit link. ( [rdrr.io/cran/performance/man/r2_mckelvey.html](https://rdrr.io/cran/performance/man/r2_mckelvey.html) ).

I don't have access to the original paper by McKelvey and Zavoina to see what formula they use for Poisson regression models.

Also note that the webpage you cited is titled "*Psuedo r-squared for logistic regression*".

Comment: This doesn't seem to quite answer the question. Probably worth explicitly clarifying that $\pi^2/3$ in the formula is the logistic distribution-specific variance, and so inappropriate for the Poisson here. The documentation you link says "*for poisson-models, the residual variance [used to calculate R2] is based on log-normal approximation, similar to the distribution-specific variance*", citing [Nakagawa, Johnson & Schielzeth (2017)](https://doi.org/10.1098/rsif.2017.0213). Although a bit unclear, it seems as though it generalises the MZ formula with this approximation.